# Finding the differences between two nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list and another nested list which is a subset of the first list:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 3], [2, 7]]
sublst = [[1, 2], [8, 3]]
```

How can I find the inner lists which are not in the sublist. The desired output using the above example is:

```
diff = [[3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 7]]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
In [42]: lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 3], [2, 7]]

In [43]: sublst = [[1, 2], [8, 3]]

In [44]: [x for x in lst if x not in sublst]
Out[44]: [[3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 7]]
```

or `filter()`:

```
In [45]: filter(lambda x:x not in sublst,lst)
Out[45]: [[3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 7]]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you convert your lists of lists to lists of tuples then you can create sets from them and use set difference operator:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6], [8, 3], [2, 7]]
sublst = [[1, 2], [8, 3]]

def tuples(lst): return [tuple(l) for l in lst]

print set(tuples(lst)) - set(tuples(sublst))
```

will print:

```
set([(5, 6), (2, 7), (3, 4)])
```

For huge lists it may be faster than evaluating `[x for x in lst if x not in sublst]`

Comment: `set(map(tuple, lst)) - set(map(tuple, sublst))` seems more Pythonic